# Use ST_AsMVTGeom for create tile of shape crossing 180 meridian

Tags: postgis, mapbox

I have a polygon that crosses the 180th meridian and a function in postgis that generates a vector tile.

SQL:

```
ST_ASMVTGEOM(ST_Transform(polygon, 3857), ST_MakeEnvelope(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, 3857), 4096, 256, true)
```

[image: Result]

How to avoid distortion of the polygon?